# How to show text on /dev/fb* c++ linux

Tags: c++, linux, framebuffer

How to show text on /dev/fb* c++ linux?
I mean like ./my_prog my_text /dev/fb0
I found only some ezfb project but it`s not what I need and no fbdev :P

Comment: Framebuffer devices are *graphical* devices.

Comment: Show the text on `/dev/tty` or *stdout*